# How can I parse this JSON object using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swift3

I'm trying to parse a JSON string returned from a new API. The returned JSON string looks like this.

```
QuerySearchResult":{
"StartAt":"1",
"Count":"40",
"TotalAvailable":"500",
"Items":[
    {"TITLE":"OST420 Generation",
    "PATH":"http:\\Test.pdf",
    "WRITE":"2016-12-12T15:47:42",
    "RANK":"32286574",
    "SIZE":"145091",
    "ISDOCUMENT":"true",
    "ID":"18548",
    "WPTASK":"Onsite Generation",
    "WPDOCTYPE":"Local Operating Procedure",
    "WPDOCREFID":"304580",
    "WPCONTENTTYPE":"Document"},
    {"TITLE":"OST420 Measurement",
    "PATH":"http:\Test33.pdf",
    .
    .
```

I'm using the code below which accepts the JSON variable but fails when I try to load item. I've tried using `Array` around `Dictionary` but it still fails. What declaration do I need to read in Items?

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
   for item in json {
      if let dict = item as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
         if let items = json["Items"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
            for rec in items {
               if let title = rec["TITLE"] as? String {
                  let xx = title
               }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you do not understand how JSON works, you can start by printing out the jsonObject - which you named "json" and see for yourself how it is stored, from there you will have a clearer picture how to access each data.

Comment: No logs or anything? How would you know which part it failed then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are not correctly iterating through `Dictionary` also instead of looping through `Dictionary` for accessing single value, try by directly accessing it through `subscripting` and the proper JSON notation of `Dictionary` in Swift 3 is `[String : Any]`.

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any],
   let queryDic = json["QuerySearchResult"] as? [String : Any],
   let items = queryDic["Items"] as? [[String : Any]] {

     for item in items {
         if let title = item["TITLE"] as? String {
              print(title)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: change `item` instead if `rec` in `if let` statement in `for` loop.

Comment: @user616076 Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 3.1 :-**

```
func parseJson(anyObj:AnyObject) {

            if  let anyObj = anyObj as? Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>> {
                self.yourArrayName = anyObj.flatMap({yourModelName(json:$0) })
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) : which can simply and easily parse the JSON more than your code.

So, how do we parse using that?

First get your response as Data()

```
let jsonData = JSON(data: results!)
```

Then here how we parse that JSON.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

enum JSONParseError : ErrorType {
    case UnknownField
    case EmptyJSON
}

extension JSONParseError : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .UnknownField:
            return "Error when parsing json because there is no field"
        case .EmptyJSON:
            return "Error when parsing empty json"
        }
    }
}

guard let querySearchResult : [String : JSON] = jsonData["QuerySearchResult"].dictionary else{
     throw JSONParseError.UnknownField
}
guard let startAt : String = querySearchResult["StartAt"].string else{
     throw JSONParseError.UnknownField
}
guard let count : String = querySearchResult["Count"].string else{
     throw JSONParseError.UnknownField
}
guard let totalAvailable : String = querySearchResult["TotalAvailable"].string else{
     throw JSONParseError.UnknownField
}
guard let items : [JSON] = querySearchResult["Items"].array else{
     throw JSONParseError.UnknownField 
}
if items.count > 0 {
     for i in 0  ..< items.count{
          guard let title = items[i]["TITLE"].string else{
                throw JSONParseError.UnknownField
          }.... //So On
     }
}else{
     throw JSONParseError.EmptyJSON         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Json returns the data into the dictionary and array format, so treat the json data like it, it makes you easier to understand.

Data in braces '{' and '}' is dictionary.

and Data in braces '[' or ']' is array.

Now start parsing the json data by the dictionary and array properties it exactly works. Or for confirmation print your json data.